# Trying to share a folder on ubuntu with an oracle vm

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, guest-additions

I'm trying to share a folder between my host (ubuntu 15) and my vm (alpine linux). 
I've been following this article: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

I'm not sure what this command means though:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host
```

I've tried this:

```
me@mydevox:~$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) ~/Downloads/rethinkdb/ ~/Documents/mysharedfolder
```

But I get this error back:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxfs'
```

I've tried both vboxfs and vboxsf

Any suggestions would be apprciated.

**EDIT 1**

One artifact I found which might help is that when I start the VM (after having installed the guest tools), in the "Devices" menu, instead of giving me a " Install Guest Additions" option, I see a "insert Guest Additions CD image" option.  When I select it, nothing happens.

In the set up of the vm, under the "storage" category, I've made sure the iso is the correct one.  It's pointing to :  /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

which exists.

Could it be because the guest os I've installed doesn't have a gui?  My guest os is alpine linux

**EDIT 2**

I found this : https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9558
But I don't know how to manually mount the CD on my guest machine...

Comment: Specify an existing but empty folder on your system as the mount point.  If you want to follow this example exactly, `mkdir ~/Documents/mysharedfolder` first to create the mount point.  (edited to match edits in question).

Comment: @user4556274 thanks. i ended up figuring that part out and so i've changed my question.  sorry about that. and thanks

Comment: given your question has changed :-) and I don't use the product, I'll leave someone else to answer.  You can see which filesystems your kernel can mount with `cat /proc/filesystems`.  If you don't see `vboxfs` in the list, it would presumably mean you haven't installed the VirtualBox guest tools correctly (or at all).

Comment: @user4556274.  thanks!  that's a good command to know about.  I have installed the guest tools ... and I have the iso mounted for the vm.  When i start the VM up though, I'm noticing that in the "Devices" menu, it has the option "insert guest tools cd" ... vs "install".